# Python3.8 Type-hinting A ctypes function

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, python-3.8, type-hinting

**Solution must support Python3.8**

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there a simpler way to express what I want (the return value of `get_ctypes_func()` is a callable, which takes params `arg_types` and returns `ret_type`)? I feel my solution is over-engineered.
- Is what I want even possible in 3.8? Or any python version for that matter?

I have the following:

```py
import ctypes
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing          import (
  TypeVar, Protocol, Generic, Optional, cast as TYPE_CAST
)

_T = TypeVar('_T', bound=type)
_T = TypeVar('_U', covariant=True, bound=type)

class CTypesCallable(Protocol[_T, _U]):
  # work around a bug in mypy: 
  # error: "CTypesCallable[_T, _U]" has no attribute "__name__"
  __name__: str

  @property
  def argtypes(self) -> Sequence[type[_T]]: ...

  def __call__(self, *args: _T) -> _U: ...

class CTypesFunction(Generic[_T, _U]):
  def __init__(self, function: CTypesCallable[_T, _U]) -> None:
    self.function = function
    return

  def __call__(self, *args: _T) -> _U:
    # do some pre-processing/arg validation
    ret = self.function(*args)
    # do some post-processing and return validation
    return ret

def get_ctypes_func(
  name:      str, 
  arg_types: Sequence[type[_T]], 
  ret_type:  Optional[type[_U]] = None
) -> CTypesFunction[_T, _U]:
  if ret_type is None:
    ret_type = ctypes.c_uint

  func = getattr(some_c_lib, name)
  return CTypesFunction(TYPE_CAST(CTypesCallable[_T, _U], func))
```

which is then used like so:

```py
ret = get_ctypes_func(
  'foo', 
  [SomePythonType, int, float]
)(SomePythonType(), 1, 2.0) # ret is int
```

Yet I get the following errors:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type
"Type[c_uint]", variable has type "Optional[Type[_U]]")  [assignment]
        ret_type = ctypes.c_uint
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: Need type annotation for "ret"  [var-annotated]
        ret = get_ctypes_func('foo', [SomePythonType, int, float])(SomePythonType(), 1, 2.0)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: Argument 1 to "__call__" of "CTypesFunction" has incompatible
type "SomePythonType"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        foo = get_ctypes_func('foo', [SomePythonType, int, float])(SomePythonType(), 1, 2.0)
                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: Argument 2 to "__call__" of "CTypesFunction" has incompatible
type "int"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        foo = get_ctypes_func('foo', [SomePythonType, int, float])(SomePythonType(), 1, 2.0)
                                                                                     ^

error: Argument 3 to "__call__" of "CTypesFunction" has incompatible
type "float"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        foo = get_ctypes_func('foo', [SomePythonType, int, float])(SomePythonType(), 1, 2.0)
                                                                                        ^~~
```

`_T` and `_U` should represent *types*, but I am not convinced that I have set them up correctly. I need to support Python3.8, so I cannot use `ParamSpec` and friends.